# Serializar resultado de uma query para JSON?

Tags: php, json, oracle

Estou adicionando o resultado de uma query em um array e estou tentando serializar para *Json*. Não estou conseguindo imprimir corretamente o meu *JSON*, poderiam me ajudar?

Meu código:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 123456);

$conn = oci_connect('teste', 'teste123', '192.168.90.3/teste');

if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$query = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT NR_SEQUENCIA, DS_GRUPO_TRABALHO FROM man_grupo_trabalho');
oci_execute($query);

$rows = array();
while($r = oci_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$rows[] = $r;
 }
$locations =(json_encode($rows));
echo $locations;

?>
```

Porém está gerando o erro:

> Warning: oci_connect(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\faturamento\conexao.php on
>   line 5
>
> Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\faturamento\conexao.php on line 9

Comment: Qual o problema? vc que imprimir o json?

Comment: Pelo menos nesse código ele não imprime o json, sugiro, remova `echo 'done!';` e adicione `echo $locations;`

Comment: Removi conforme o último histórico mas ainda deu erro: Warning: oci_connect(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\faturamento\conexao.php on line 5

Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\faturamento\conexao.php on line 9

Comment: Mas isso ai parece ser erro da consulta, vc pode fazer um exemplo simples p testar o json, crie um arquivo novo com esse código `<?php json_encode(array('msg' => 'teste', 'data' => date('H:i:s')));`

Comment: realmente os dados de conexão na publicação estava errado. Ja mudei mas o browser de internet deixou de imprimir a palavra done e passou a assumir vazio, ou seja, pagina sem resultado

Comment: Se vc jogar essa consulta direto no oracle da algum erro?

Comment: qual consulta? SELECT NR_SEQUENCIA, DS_GRUPO_TRABALHO FROM man_grupo_trabalho

Comment: Essa consulta mesmo, da erro no banco?

Comment: O resultado parece normalmente no banco de dados oracle, ou seja, visualizo todos os registros da tabela

Comment: veja se assim retorna a mensagem de erro `oci_execute($query) or die(print_r(oci_error($conn)));`

Comment: Pagina continua sem resultado, mesmo acrescentando esse ultimo código

Comment: parece não tem nada a ver com json... a mensagem de erro é clara sobre o erro na conexão com o oracle...  corrija isso que provavelmente funcionará o restante.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo esta outra resposta:

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605099/oci-connect-works-only-from-command-line**

o oracle não está referenciado em seu apache, e colocando estas linhas

`putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1");
 putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib");`